# Jump to the line texmaker is not working

Tags: texmaker, forward-inverse-search

The version of my TEX is 4.41, the  "jump to the line texmaker" is not working? I had follow the previous advice about adding synctex=1 to pdfLatex and I found that it is already set by default. Can you help me please in this regard.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you add some details about your operating system?

Answer (score 3):

The following will help to configure both forward/inverse searches.

**Make sure you type the correct installation directory of Texmaker and SumatraPDF.**

1. In Texmaker, go to `Options > Configure Texmaker > Commands`
2. In `External Viewer` field (in case you are using SumatraPDF), type `"C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" -1 -s @%.tex %.pdf`

[image]

3. In SumatraPDF, go to `Settings > Options`, then type `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Texmaker\texmaker.exe" "%f" -line %l` in `Set inverse search command-line`

[image]

### TeXstudio

In case you are using TeXstudio

1. In TeXstudio, go to `Options > Configure TeXstudio > Commands`
2. In `External PDF Viewer` field (**in case you are using SumatraPDF**), type

   ```
   "C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" -reuse-instance -inverse-search "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/TeXstudio/texstudio.exe\" \"%%f\" -line %%l" -forward-search "?c:am.tex" @ "?am.pdf"
   ```

[image]

3. In SumatraPDF, go to `Settings > Options`, then, in `Set inverse search command-line`, type

   ```
   "C:/Program Files (x86)/TeXstudio/texstudio.exe" "%f" -line %l
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it on Windows and Mac OS with version 4.5. There a small window appears on the bottom after pressing Ctrl + G or cmd + G. Enter the line number and press Enter. This works for me. You might want to update your version of texmaker.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented everything that is suggested here, and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786280/texmaker-shortcuts-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04). Implementing these may be necessary. However, what finally worked for me is, selecting the Quick Build option to PdfLatex+ViewPDF. Earlier this option was set to Lulatex+ViewPDF.